# How to create float action button menu with constraint layout?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

How can I make floating button menu with two button as child, an one as main.
At present, I just can make one floating button.

Basically I combine CoordinatorLayout to get AppBarLayout and ConstraintLayout as the content.

The CoordinatorLayout named **activity_incoming_lokal.xml** looked like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IncomingLokalActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_incoming_lokal" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And for the content looked like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".IncomingLokalActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_incoming_lokal"
>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/incomingLokalNomorKendaraan"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/nomor_plat_kendaraan"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:autofillHints="@string/nomor_plat_kendaraan" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you use the templates that come with Android Studio, you can insert a Basic Activity ( https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates#BasicActivity ) and it comes with constraint-layout and a floating action button. You can see it's layout code and build accordingly next time.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Now I need Fab Menu

Comment: Did you look into Github? There are many ready to use libraries with various licences you can use. Start here: https://github.com/HarinTrivedi/FABRevealMenu-master
https://github.com/anshulagarwal2k/GooeyMenu you might need to inquire about this project's license.

Comment: @Naseem K decide to create by my own. Thanks

Comment: If you do build your own FAB Menu, do answer your question here.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
```

This will functionally position the bottom-right corner of your FAB at the top-left corner of the screen. In other words, you've constrained the FAB to be off-screen.

Chances are good that you meant you want the right of the FAB to be at the right of the screen, and the bottom of the FAB to be at the bottom of the screen. So use these instead:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to move the FAB to content.
So. my code looked like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IncomingLokalActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_incoming_lokal" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the content looked like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".IncomingLokalActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_incoming_lokal"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:id="@+id/fabUpload"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/fabGallery"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:id="@+id/fabCamera"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:background="@color/tealGreen"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/tealGreen"
        android:id="@+id/fabMain"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```